# Azure Function using v2 programming model for debugging

Tags: python, azure, encryption, azure-functions, pgp

I have inherited the following code in Azure Functions and I want to ensure if this correct and find out the correct way to call this utilizing Python Azure Functions v2 programming model.

```
import os
import gnupg
import azure.functions as func

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/tmp')

class PGPDecryption:
def __init__(self, prikey):
    self.fullkey = prikey

def decrypt(self, blob_data):
    key_data = self.fullkey.strip()
    gpg.import_keys(key_data)
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(blob_data)
    return str(decrypted_data)

# Blob Trigger for input and Blob Output binding for decrypted file
@func.blob_input(name='inputBlob', path='input-container/{name}', 
connection='AzureWebJobsStorage')
@func.blob_output(name='outputBlob', path='output-container/{name}.decrypted', 
connection='AzureWebJobsStorage')
def main(inputBlob: func.InputStream, outputBlob: func.Out[func.InputStream], context: 
func.Context):
prikey = '<Your PGP Private Key>'  # Replace with your PGP private key
decryptor = PGPDecryption(prikey)
decrypted_data = decryptor.decrypt(inputBlob.read())

# Writing decrypted data to output binding
outputBlob.set(decrypted_data)
```

The objective is for the code to get a file from Azure Blob and decrpyt it and put it back to another Azure Blob location.
Does the code actually achieve this and how can I debug this?

Comment: You are not using any trigger in your code you need to use trigger too.
check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python) for using http trigger

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya The code seems to have the Blob  Trigger indeed,,,does that not suffice?

Comment: You are only using input and output binding but there is no any trigger to run those code. It need to have a trigger too.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the code actually achieve this and how can I debug this?

To debug you can use logging and to test the code(taken a sample code, you can use yours):

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="rithwiktest1",
                               connection="rithwiktest1")
@app.blob_output(arg_name='outputBlob', path='testrithwik2/test',
                 connection='rithwiktest1') 
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream,outputBlob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    outputBlob.set("Hello Rithwik Bojja")
```

Here, this azure blob trigger gets triggered when a new blob is added and then it created a new file in destination like below:

[image]

You need to check if a new blob is created or not.